# Angular patchValue changes in Parent component not reflected in Child Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have tried searching similar questions that suits my use-case but couldn't find it. I have wasted 3 days on this thing already! Any help will be appreciated.

Here's a scenario:

1. Reactive Form (FormGroup - form) is defined and initialised in the parent component.
2. This parent component has multiple child components and each take the full "form" as there formGroup.
3. Later, I add a edit route using ID. Then, based on ID I am using patchValue to change some of the group values using values coming from MongoDB.

The issue: PatchValue isn't working. It results in empty values. Don't have any idea why this is happening.

Code:Parent component

```js
export class CurrentBillingInfoComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup; // reactive form which is being passed to child components
    edit: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private _fb: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private xpebillingService: XpebillingService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.licensingService.isPageLoading = true;
        this.initialiseForm();
        this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
            const billingId = params.get('id');
            console.log('Billing ID: ', billingId);
            if (billingId) {
                this.edit = true;
                this.getBillingData(billingId);
            }
        });
    }

    private getBillingData(billingId: string) {
        this.xpebillingService.getXpebilling(billingId).subscribe(
            (xpebilling: { data: IXpeBillingForm; meta: {} }) => {
                console.log('Fill edit billing form values', xpebilling?.data);
                this.editBillingForm(xpebilling?.data);
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.log('Fill edit billing form error');
                this.notificationService.error(ERROR, error);
            }
        );
    }

    private editBillingForm(xpebilling: IXpeBillingForm) {
        this.form.patchValue({
            [XPEBILLING.xCompanyID]: xpebilling.xCompanyID,
            [XPEBILLING.xCompanyName]: 'TESTING_COMPANY_NAME',
            [XPEBILLING.xBusinessID]: xpebilling.xBusinessID,
            [XPEBILLING.xBusinessName]: xpebilling.xBusinessName
        });
    }

    private initialiseForm() {
        this.form = this._fb.group({
            [XPEBILLING.xCompanyID]: ['', [Validators.required]],
            [XPEBILLING.xCompanyName]: ['', [Validators.required]],
            [XPEBILLING.xBusinessID]: ['', [Validators.required]],
            [XPEBILLING.xBusinessName]: ['', [Validators.required]],
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am setting a flag "edit" to be true on finding the 'id' in query params. I can see the values change in the formGroup within console, just not in the child component view.

Code: How I am passing it to child

```html
<app-payer-billing-setup [form]="form" [edit]="edit"></app-payer-billing-setup>
```

Code: How I take it inside child component

```js
@Input() form: FormGroup;
@Input() edit: boolean;

constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private companyService: CompanyService,
        private notificationService: NotificationService,
        public licensingService: LicensingService,
        public cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.licensingService.isPageLoading = true;
        this.watchCompanyChange(this.edit);
    }

    ngAfterContentChecked() {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }

    watchCompanyChange(isEditing: boolean): void {
        this.licensingService.isPageLoading = true;
        console.log('Watching company...');
        this.companyService.watchCompanyID$.subscribe(async (compID) => {
            if (!compID) {
                throw new Error(COMP_ID_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            this.companyID = compID ? compID : this.companyService.companyID.getValue() ? this.companyService.companyID.getValue() : '';
            this.setFormControlForCompany('id');
            console.log({ companyID: this.companyID });
            if(!isEditing) {
                this.httpService.get('xbcCompanies', this.companyID).subscribe(
                    (response: Response | any) => {
                        const _companyData = response.data;
                        console.log('This is company data', _companyData);
                        this.companyName = _companyData.xName || '';
                        this.setFormControlForCompany('name');
    
                        console.log({ companyName: this.companyName });
                    },
                    (error: any) => {
                        console.log(error, 'error while fetching company');
                        this.notificationService.error(ERROR, NO_COMPANY_FOUND);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                console.log("xCompanyName values: ", this.form.value);
                console.log("xCompanyName: ", this.form.value.xCompanyName);
                console.log("xCompanyName value: ", this.form.get('xCompanyName').value);
                this.companyName = this.form.value.xCompanyName;
                this.setFormControlForCompany('name');
            }
            
            try {
                this.businesses = await this.fetchBusinesses(this.companyID);
                if (Array.isArray(this.businesses) && this.businesses.length > 0) {
                    if(!isEditing) {
                        this.selectedBizID = this.businesses[0]?._id;
                        this.bizAsCustID = this.businesses[0]?.xAsCustomerID;
                        this.businessName = this.businesses[0]?.xName;  
                    } else {
                        this.selectedBizID = this.form.value.xBusinessID;
                        this.businessName = this.form.value.xBusinessName;
                        for (const business of this.businesses) {
                            if(business?._id === this.selectedBizID) {
                                this.bizAsCustID = business?.xAsCustomerID;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log({
                        "isEditing: ": isEditing,
                        "companyID:": this.companyID,
                        "companyName: ": this.companyName,
                        "Selected Business ID: ": this.selectedBizID,
                        "Business name: ": this.businessName,
                        "Business as customer: ": this.bizAsCustID
                    })
                    this.setFormControlForBusiness();
                    this.fetchCustomers();
                } else {
                    this.clearFormControlForBusiness();
                    this.notificationService.error(ERROR, NO_BUSINESS_FOUND);
                }
                this.licensingService.isPageLoading = false;
            } catch (error) {
                this.clearFormControlForBusiness();
                let message = error.message ? error.message : FAILED_TO_FETCH_BUSINESS;
                this.notificationService.error(ERROR, message);
                this.licensingService.isPageLoading = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Code on HTML end of Child Component:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
                <label> Payer Business: </label>
                <div class="merch_type mt-1">
                    <select (change)="onBusinessChange($event)" class="form-control form-control-sm h-2125">
                        <option *ngFor="let biz of businesses" [value]="biz?._id" [selected]="biz?._id === selectedBizID">
                            {{ biz?.xName }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label> Payer Customer: </label>
                <div class="merch_type mt-1">
                    <div class="merch-info" *ngIf="licensingService.isBusinessChanging">
                        <p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i> Loading...</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="merch-info" *ngIf="!licensingService.isBusinessChanging">
                        <p *ngIf="customerData.length">
                            {{ customerData[0].xName ? customerData[0].xName : '-' }}
                        </p>
                        <p *ngIf="!customerData.length">No Customers found.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: `I can see the values change in the formGroup within console, just not in the child component view.`  Where exactly you expect the changes to be visible in child component view?

Comment: biz?.xName in child component html basically. Sometimes it appears and some times gives error.

Comment: watch the angular parent component patchValue changes in the child component - I think this is what precisely I want.

Comment: You already have `form` instance in Child component. You can always listen to its changes via `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {// your logic})`

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically take the patchValue operation changes I am doing in the parent component based on route param 'id'?